# Delete Last Row in Group

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a workbook with information sorted by an UKey; I need to delete the last row in each group.

[image: Like so,]
In this example, I need to remove row 524; ranges between UKeys are not fixed.

I've tried calculating a new column to reference the previous row with no luck, re-sorting the data and removing the first row, playing with index...

Help!

Comment: Looks like you have sorted on `Ukey` rather than `ID`. Do you want to delete each last row of `Ukey` 's?

Comment: yes, let me modify the wording. so it's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
let
    group = Table.Group(YourLastStep, "UKey", {"temp", Table.RemoveLastN}),
    combine = Table.Combine(group[temp])
in
    combine
```

Note, if there is single row in the group - it will be deleted. If you need keep this single row, then use this code:

```
let
    group = Table.Group(YourLastStep, "UKey", {"temp", each if Table.RowCount(_) = 1
                                                       then _ else Table.RemoveLastN(_)}),
    combine = Table.Combine(group[temp])
in
    combine
```

Comment: This actually pays the bills, TY! Would you mind sharing what does the code do? I think group, groups the table by UKey, but i dont understand the 'temp' and 'Table.RemoveLastN argument. Nor the follorinw step.

Comment: It's grouping the table into chunks of matching `UKey` and removing the last N (default 1) rows for each `UKey` group and then combining the groups back into a single table.

Comment: temp - just name of new column, you may choose anything you wish. Then we specify function, which applied to every group. It's short for {"temp", each Table.RemoveLastN(_)}. Table.RemoveLastN function without the 2nd argument removes the last row of the table. Now  temp column contains tables without the last row for every group. Next step just combines all tables in temp column.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a separate query where you Group By `UKey` and take the max as the aggregate for your timestamp column. This should give you a table with `Ukey` and its timestamp for the row you want to remove. Once you have that, you can do a left anti join on your original table (matching on both columns, not just `UKey`) to remove the rows that exist in the grouped table.